# Could not allocate space for object in database because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could not allocate space for object  in database  because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.
 Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

I am getting this error even when I have enough Hard Disk Space. Please advice. I have checked related topics but not helpful.

Comment: I actually got this error 2 days ago, when I was trying to run a massive aggregation query.  The reality was that I was joining a 300K+ table to a table with several million records, and there just wasn't enough space to do it.  My solution was to come up with a different query.

Comment: "setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup" - Have you done it?

Comment: Is the database file set to auto grow? If so, by what amount? The unhelpful default in many versions of SQL Server is "10% of the current size", which may well still exceed your available disk space if the file is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 4):

You should configure *Maximum File Size* and *AutoGrowth* of primary files. You can find the settings with following instructions;

**Move to YourDatabase -> Properties -> Files and find the files which are inside the primary filegroup** and configure the Maximum File Size and AutoGrowth settings.